# All combinations of counts

Tags: sql, count

I have a table, with columns
product_id, status, for example:

| product_id | status |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ok |
| 2 | bad |
| 1 | ok |
| 3 | bad |
| 2 | bad |
| 1 | ok |

I'd like to show count of all possible combinations of product_ID and status:

| product_id | status | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ok | 3 |
| 1 | bad | 0 |
| 2 | ok | 0 |
| 2 | bad | 2 |
| 3 | ok | 0 |
| 3 | bad | 1 |

The solution I've found is that I could use a Cartesian join and then union it with regular counts and aggregate the results (works fine):

```
SELECT product_id, status, SUM(cnt) FROM (
---all combinations, no count
    SELECT DISTINCT t1.product_id, t2.status, 0 AS cnt
    FROM 
    details t1,
    details t2

    UNION

---counts of existing combinations
    SELECT DISTINCT product_id, status, COUNT(status) AS cnt
    FROM details
    GROUP BY product_id, status) AS T1
GROUP BY product_id, status
```

Now I am wondering, is here a better way to do it?

I learning SQL with PostgreSQL and Access SQL. Comments are added to clarify (left-out in Access code).

Answer (score 1):

Use `CROSS JOIN` to build all combinations and top up with a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT p.product_id, s.status, COUNT(t.any_not_null_column)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT product_id FROM t) AS p
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT status FROM t) AS s
LEFT JOIN t ON p.product_id = t.product_id AND s.status = t.status
GROUP BY p.product_id, s.status
```

Comment: This is a great solution

Answer (score 0):

The following is a Postgres solution (a database I strongly recommend over MS Access).  The idea is to generate all the rows and then use `left join` and `group by` to get the counts you want:

```
select p.product_id, s.status, count(d.product_id)
from (select distinct product_id from details) p cross join
     (values ('ok'), ('bad')) s left join
     details d
     on d.product_id = p.product_id and d.status = s.status
group by p.product_id, s.status;
```

Note:  You might have other tables that have the list of products and/or statuses that you want.

An equivalent version in MS Access (which would also work in Postgres) might look like:

```
select p.product_id, s.status, count(d.product_id)
from ((select distinct product_id from details) p, 
      (select distinct status from details) s
     ) left join
     details d
     on d.product_id = p.product_id and
        d.status = s.status
group by p.product_id, s.status;
```